# Django setting root url path for redirects

Tags: django, redirect, nginx

I have a project with the following components:

- a single page backbone application for the web client
- a django app for the api
- nginx in front to direct requests to backbone and django

In my nginx conf, I direct the requests to django if the path starts with /api ,
otherwise, I serve the files directly (index.html and static files)

This setup works fine, the problem arises when django needs to redirect the url. Say, for instance, I request /api/users , as I have forgotten the trailing slash, django automatically redirects this, but instead of redirecting to /api/users/ , it redirects to /users/ as django does not know that I am hosting it on /api. How can I configure django to handle this redirect correctly?

Comment: The best solution would be to configure nginx and your app server to pass the `SCRIPT_NAME`. Alternatively, you can set [`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#force-script-name).

Comment: I got it to work with by passing the SCRIPT_NAME, thank you